# Reduce threads to reduce CPU usage of powershell process through powershell command

Tags: multithreading, powershell, cpu, cpu-usage

I have used a Fake cpu usage script in powershell,when i run it CPU usage increases,i can see the thread count. Now i have to reduce/increase the threadcount inorder reduce the CPU usage.
Below is the script used for increasing CPU usage. Please help with any powershell command that would reduce/increase thread count for reducing CPU usage. or any other method to reduce CPU usage in this script.
Below is the main part of loop script,by running this in powershell CPU usage increases

```
# Code
$num = 2
If ([$num -gt 1])) {
 
 $ThreadCount=(Get-Process -ProcessName Powershell | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count
 $ErrorMessage = "Before CPU Saturation threadcount:" + $ThreadCount
 write-AppEventLog $ErrorMessage
 
 $result = 1; 
 foreach ($number in 1..2147483647) {
 $ThreadCount1=(Get-Process -ProcessName Powershell | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count
 foreach ($number in 1..2147483647) {
 $result = $result * $number
 $ErrorMessage1 = " CPU Saturation threadcount:" + $ThreadCount1
 write-AppEventLog $ErrorMessage1
 }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a single-threaded loop. Each operation like `Get-Process`, `Select-Object` uses its own thread, but this is still a single-threaded loop.

Comment: When i log the thread count from this loop,threadcount varies from 5- 15. What should i do to reduce/increase thread count and observe reduction in CPU usage? should i create a multithreaded script which would increase cpu usage? any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple threads, you can use jobs

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
# do the thing
}
# Example infinite loop
while($true)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    # do the thing
    }
}
```